# How to use Displaytag to show a DAO?

Tags: jsp, dao, jsp-tags, displaytag

---

**Got it to work, but the table has no style, only text. How can I fix?**

---

I want to use `displaytag` to show a contacts list.
Using the `<c:forEach ..>` it works fine, but I don't know how to do this with `displaytag`.

`displaytag-1.2.jar` is in \WEB-INF\lib.

What is wrong?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

.
.
.


    <jsp:useBean id="dao" class="caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDao" />


    <display:table name="${dao.lista}" />
.
.
.
```

The error changes sometimes when I keep hiting F5.

ERROR 1

```
type Exception report

    message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) . . .
```

ERROR 2

```
        type Exception report

        message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.lista_002dcontato_002ddisplay_jsp

        description The se

rver encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.lista_002dcontato_002ddisplay_jsp org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.lista_002dcontato_002ddisplay_jsp java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: You don't have the required libraries in the webapp, or have a different version of them. See http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/install.html

Comment: It worked! Now my table is showing, but there is only text, no color or style... how can I fix?

Comment: By declaring CSS rules. You can use the examples as a starting point.